# how to reset table's id(Django)

Tags: django, pandas

```
#leader_board
<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #dddddd;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ng" style="background-color: #eeeeee;text-align: center;">#</th>
                    <th class="ng" style="background-color: #eeeeee;text-align: center;">user</th>
                    <th class="ng" style="background-color: #eeeeee;text-align: center;">submission_date</th>
                    <th class="ng" style="background-color: #eeeeee;text-align: center;">rank</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for submission in submissions.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="ng">{{submission.id}}</td>
                    <td class="ng">{{submission.user_name}}</td>
                    <td class="ng">{{submission.submission_time}}</td>
                    <td class="ng">{{submission.user_score}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="{% url 'sub_page' %}" class="btn btn-dark pull-right">submit</a>
    </div>
```

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'parrotadmin')
    user_ranking = models.FloatField(default=0)
    submission_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/',
                                       default=None)
    submission_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    submission_time = models.DateTimeField('Submission Date', auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'submission'
        verbose_name_plural = 'submissions'
        db_table = 'parrot_con'
        ordering = ('-user_score',)
```

```
#output example(mine)
------------------------
#    user      time       score
3     #       ######      0.98
1     #       ######      0.88
2     #       ######      0.78
------------------------
#what I want
1     #       ######      0.98
2     #       ######      0.88
3     #       ######      0.78
```

I'm trying to make leader-board for my study group with django.
What I'm struggling with is resetting index of my table to show user's rank

- plus) If there's any master of django, I have a question

  I have a code made with pandas and sklearn accuracy score. If I want to open uploaded csv file and get score, which function do I have to add that code??(ex. views.py--> submissionlistview, submission, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Replace {{submission.id}} with {{forloop.counter}}

```
<td class="ng">{{submission.id}}</td> # wrong
<td class="ng">{{forloop.counter}}</td> # Right
```

You can't give model instance id as a table serial no if you are ordering objects.

Comment: thank you so much! Now my table look much better!! :)